# Error #2032: Stream Error

Tags: flash

I am using an `.swf` file which takes data from an XML file to run.
I have added this `swf` file into my dot net web application in an iframe.

But when I run the application, flash gives the error:

```
ERROR #2032 Stream Error
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: could you show us some code, and a stack trace and where the error is?

Comment: Also, what is the relation to Java, JavaScript, JQuery, SQL-server here? (I removed these tags and added *flash* instead.)

Comment: @Manoj: please give us more information, this question is not really answerable.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491902/flex-http-request-error-2032

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From a quick google search it seems that the problem is a file or url couldn't be found be the HTTPservice.

Here are the links where I found this information:

http://www.judahfrangipane.com/blog/2007/02/15/error-2032-stream-error/

http://curtismorley.com/2008/02/08/actionscript-error-2032/

Comment: I think the best answer is the comment by Mike Chambers in the first link you sent.

If you run into this using URLLoader, listen for the:
flash.events.HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS

and in AIR :
flash.events.HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS

It should give you some more information (such as the status code being returned from the server).

Comment: The first link is no longer working, but I think this is the new one: https://flexcapacitorblog.wordpress.com/2007/02/15/error-2032-stream-error/

Answer (score 12):

Just to clarify my comment (it's illegible in a single line)

I think the best answer is the comment by Mike Chambers in this link (http://www.judahfrangipane.com/blog/2007/02/15/error-2032-stream-error/) by Hunter McMillen.

A note from Mike Chambers:

If you run into this using URLLoader, listen for the:

```
flash.events.HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS
```

and in AIR :

```
flash.events.HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS
```

It should give you some more information (such as the status code being returned from the server).

Comment: The linked blog post is gone.

Comment: Most likely this is the updated link: https://flexcapacitorblog.wordpress.com/2007/02/15/error-2032-stream-error/

Answer (score 2):

This error also occurs if you did not upload the various rsl/swc/flash-library that your swf file might expect. 
You may upload this RSL or missing swc or tweak your compiler options cf. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-1a92eab212e75b9d8b2-7ffe.html#WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-1a92eab212e75b9d8b2-7ff5