# Flash CS6 project panel error Error #2032: Stream Error

Tags: flash

After uninstalling CS5.5 and installing CS6, my project tab is broken ! Here's what it shows :

```
Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: file:///C|/Users/Eric/AppData/Local/Adobe/Flash CS6/en_US/Configuration/WindowSWF/framework_4.5.1.21328.swz
```

Does anyone know how to reset the project thing in flash ? there must be a config file somewhere tho i can't find it !!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the "project tab is broken". If the error is occurring with the code from a specific project, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507461/error-2032-stream-error may help. But it sounds like your problem is happening to everything in CS6, not just one project?

Comment: No this code is showing inside the Project tab instead of the tree view...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find framework_4.5.1.21328.swz and another file mx_4.5.1.21328.swz in Adobe Flex SDK 4.5.1 in url http://download.cnet.com/Adobe-Flex-SDK/3000-2383_4-10644675.html. Just copy these two files to the path you show.