# Output and Compiler Errors Window not working in CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, trace

Since I've updated Flash CS5 to CS6, my trace function doesn't show anything in Output window.

I've checked my code, even inserting errors, and no tracks or errors showed in both windows. This is the code:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;


    public class Main extends MovieClip {


        public function Main() {

            trace("Hello World");
            btn1a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, salute);
        }
        private function salute(e:MouseEvent){
            trace("Hello World 2");         
            /*trace(e.target.x);
            trace(e.target.y);
            trace(e.target.width);
            trace(e.target.height);
            trace(e.target.valueOf());*/

            }       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify if the [filter level](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WS3e7c64e37a1d85e1e229110db38dec34-7fc2a.html#WS3e7c64e37a1d85e1e229110db38dec34-7faba) of your output panel is **NOT** "None" which prevent any information from appearing in the Output panel; and select "Verbose" which send all information to the Output panel.

[image]

Hope that can help.

Comment: No akmozo, doesn't work. I saw an error in the project window, this one: `Error #2032: Sequence Error. URL: file:////Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Users/Dani/Library/Application%20Support/Adobe/Flash%20CS6/es%5FES/Configuration/WindowSWF/framework_4.5.1.21328.swz`

Comment: @DGM.- Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366127/flash-cs6-project-panel-error-error-2032-stream-error) may be it can help.

Comment: Thanks again, but doesn't work. Finally I need to copy-paste my code in every new file, re-build and it does work. Tough solution.

Comment: @DGM.- The most important is that you got a solution for your problem.