# Flash AS3 Error 2032

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, post, urlloader

I am trying to send some data using URlLoader and urlVariables(this also includes encoded images ) on a button click to Php Script.Its a POST request. My client says - "Most of the times it works fine but sometimes it gives an "Error 2032"" but i am unable to replicate the error. I am listening to HTTP_STATUS, IO_ERROR and COMPLETE events. Php script file url is correct and the cross domain policy file is in place. I am using CSS 5.5 & AS3 . Any Thoughts. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should collect the data server-side, probably during a couple of days, and record the time(s) when client received the error. This way you would be able to replicate the data exchange and then debug your SWF according to the dataset received.

Comment: `Error32: Stream Error` means that what you tried to load is not fully available or non existant. Probably an internet connection issue. Does "sometimes" actually mean "really big file"?? That has a load attempt done before all bytes are fully received/complete? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507461/error-2032-stream-error

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply @VC.One. Not really big files but every request does contain 3-4 images converted into byte array and some string data. I already refered that link.

Comment: Is base64 involved in this? If not I think it's be safer if you break things up into separate smaller bytearrays and just guarantee that each items start/end bytes get there intact (instead of 4 in one). Your client is not helping with just "sometimes". Like @Vesper said, you/they need to take note of details when it happens. could be anything from filesize to interrupted signal every time a door opens nearby y'no..

Comment: Yes,i am using base64.The flow is -I am using separate button to load different images. on click of button i am converting the image into a byte array and then storing it into a variable. on final submit i am sending these images with data in a single request to php script. Should i start sending images one by one on individual button clicks? Like you and @Vesper said i need more details to find a solution to this.

Comment: Could it be due to caching?