# Flex: HTTPService error #2032 every time

Tags: java, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I had read this:
[Flex: HTTP request error #2032](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491902/flex-http-request-error-2032)

And this:
http://www.judahfrangipane.com/blog/2007/02/15/error-2032-stream-error/

Trying to figure out whats going on, and im failing big time so far...

I can not consume even the simplest servlet with HTTPService component, they all fail and i have no idea why.

tryed Post and Get as well.

HTTP request error

```
Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Error de secuencia. URL: http://localhost:8080/root/test"]. URL: http://localhost:8080/root/test
```

Flex:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
        <fx:Declarations>
            <s:HTTPService
                id="httpSerciseTest"
                url="/root/test"
                method="GET"
                resultFormat="e4x"
                useProxy="false"
                result="resultHandler(event)"
                fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString+
                '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail,
                'Error: '+event.fault.faultCode)"/>
        </fx:Declarations>
        <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                import mx.controls.Alert;
                import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
                import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

                [Bindable]private var xmlResult:XML;
                private function creationCompleteHandler():void
                {
                    httpSerciseTest.send();
                }
                private function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
                {
                    xmlResult=event.result as XML;
                }
            ]]>
        </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Java servlet:

```
public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4484874511692568559L;
    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException
    {
        response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
        try{
            PrintWriter writer=response.getWriter();
            writer.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n");
            writer.println("<root>");
            writer.println("<folder label=\"Repository\"/>");
            writer.println("<folder label=\"Documentation\"/>");
            writer.println("</root>");
        }catch (IOException IOE){
            throw IOE;
        }
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <display-name>test</display-name>
        <servlet-class>java_servlets.Test</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

also, im using filereference uploading and downloading files with servlets and they're working fine, but if i call the very same servlets with HTTPService, they fail too...

Edit: localhost:8080/root/test shows a HTTP Status 404 page.

2nd Edit: I copy pasted the doGet from this test example to my file upload servlet and its working, HTTPService can consume it from there, but not from the new ones i created, including this test...

Comment: Be sure to use a tool such as the Flash Builder Network Monitor to look at the packets being sent back and forth.  Also, I suggest you include the full error as part of your question, as that may help diagnose

Comment: I enabled network monitor and run my short servlet test, got the same error as well, but nothing came up in network monitor =/

Comment: Okay so opening this path in a browser works correctly I presume http://localhost:8080/root/test you may want to add the local path to the running swf to your flash player trust settings (possibly you're getting some form of cross domain security issue, this would fix the problem, if the client swf and service will be at different domains you'll need to read up on using a crossdomain.xml file)

Comment: I'd suggest first debugging the service/servlet by itself to be sure that's working correctly then shift focus to the swf if you haven't already.

Comment: sorry, just got back home and im having problems runing my project:  
Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed: url: 'http://localhost:8080/root/messagebroker/amf'
As soon as its up, imma try the suggestions.

Comment: i just spend the last 3 hours trying to fix this new error, turns out it was this:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/498357

Comment: turning on Flash Builder Network Monitor became into a real nightmare, and i wasnt even able to disable it, i had to do it in actionscript.properties...

Comment: @shaunhusain my app its an intranet, i dont have a crossdomain.xml file cuz im afraid of the implications: http://www.jamesward.com/2009/11/08/how-bad-crossdomain-policies-expose-protected-data-to-malicious-applications/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i got it working, two things were happening:

1.- You cant consume a servlet's Post method without any parameters, i did change method="POST" for method="GET" as shown in the example, but sometimes i have a hard time with eclipse recompiling changes on my java source folder, i usually have to do a clean and restart the JBoss for eclipse to fully deploy new changes.

2.- As shaunhusain suggested, i tried the url localhost:8080/root/test expecting to see the xml but i got a 404, so the servlet wasnt even avaliable in the first place, and so far, i still cant get the Test servlet to be avaliable, but i got the one needed working, i still dont know wich part of the War is for the compiled servlets, or how to make sure they get deployed.

Imma try to figure out how the java servlets are recognized by ecplise and then deployed on my own, but if someone kindly explains the process or gives a good source, i will mark it as the correct answer, since this was the main reason of my problem.

Edit: One more thing, fault event is not getting my thrown exceptions,  when something fails on the doPost or doGet function, i get a HTTP request error #2032 instead of the real error message.

Edit: Found it!, turns out eclipse randomly fails to publish full changes and some servlets never get published.
this is the only reliably way i found to get it working so far:

delete the server from the servers view,
go to
"workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\publish",
delete all your publish.xml files, then
restart eclipse.

http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t88527.html

This also happens with messagebroekr/amf very frequently.

Comment: With regard to your edit, I think if an exception is thrown server side it'll result in an ErrorEvent sub-class of some sort on the client side and the event itself should contain the response from the server, however if the event isn't being listened for it'll create an actual run-time exception on the flash side (which is I think what you're seeing, if you run in debug mode when you hit the error I wonder if you would be able to see the rootCause or something like that)  A bit on ErrorEvents here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/ErrorEvent.html

Comment: With regard to problem 1 I've also had problems with using Tomcat in Eclipse Indigo where I have to clean most of the time or else the container just crashes when I make java changes (I'm a total noob to servlet programming but have a lot of educational experience with Java).  So I'd also like an answer on that one if you figure it out.